# How to remove duplicate chars form string? - JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to remove duplicate characters from string, for example:
"abcdab" => "abcd"
"aaabbc" => "abc"
How to do it on JS (maybee with using $.unique or something else) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
function unique(str) {
  var result = '';
  for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if(result.indexOf(str[i]) < 0) {
      result += str[i];
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(
  unique('abcdab'),
  unique('aaabbc')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would turn the string into an array with split("") and pass it to underscore's unique function then join it back up.

```
$.unique("abcdab".split("")).join("");
```

edit: working jsbin http://jsbin.com/wakonepala/1/edit?js,console

Comment: FWIW, I like my answer better than any of the "marked as duplicate" answer as it is shorter.

Comment: That's jQuery, and doesn't work.

Comment: Thank, this is also a good solution.

Comment: Hey @Amit, I added a jsbin to show it working.

Comment: Again, it's ***not underscore***, and it [***doesn't work***](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/) (only works for DOM objects, sorts original array in place - so modifies input and returns a sorted result)